# JMeter - call __stringToFile function from Groovy/Beanshell

Tags: jmeter

For example function __machineName can be called from groovy:

```
def machineName = new org.apache.jmeter.functions.MachineName().compute()
```

Can anyone advise how can I call function __stringToFile in a similar way?

This function has 4 parameters:
1 - file name
2 - content
3 - append (true/false)(optional)
4 - file encoding (optional)

I would like to pass a Groovy variable (or JMeter variable) as a "content" parametr.

I need to write to a one csv file from severals threads after end of the thread loop and __StringToFile is probably the only one safe way? (prevents "race condition" during writing).

Answer (score 1):

> __StringToFile is probably the only one safe way?

no, it's not (unless you call it under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller))

If you need to write values from multiple threads into a single file consider using either [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property or [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)

If you're still looking for a way to write a string to file from Groovy it's as simple as:

```
new File('/path/to/your.file') << 'your string here'
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the Critical section controller (CSC).  
And JSR223 sampler with groovy script in CSC can work.  
   
  
Is  
`new File('/path/to/your.file') << 'your string here'`  
enough to append string to existing file?  
  
  
But I would like to try stringToFile  
(based on this reply: [link](stackoverflow.com/a/66597654/16917808)  in another thread).  
  
  
  
I need to write to file at the ends of the thread loops so I suppose "Sample Variables property" or "Flexible File Writer" is not a good way...